# Nominatim search results are always empty

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

In my server's Nominatim I'm trying to search anything on the map.
For example I'm trying to search London on my map . I always got :

```
 No search results found
 Addresses and postcodes are approximate
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix it ?
Here are links to website and xml results to anything

```
  [1]: http://91.185.184.63/nominatim/search.php?q=London&viewbox=-151.18,66.02,151.18,-66.02
  [2]: http://91.185.184.63/nominatim/search?q=london&format=xml "XML Results"
```

Comment: Have the import and indexing steps been successful?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem. Did you find out what caused the problem?

Comment: I'm still looking for any kind of clue about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nominatim with a single-country dataset then searching for anything outside of that country returns an empty response with status 200.

So if you installed Nominatim using Docker and followed the official readme file then you will be using the dataset of Monaco only.

```
docker run -it \
  -e PBF_URL=https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/monaco-latest.osm.pbf \
  -e REPLICATION_URL=https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/monaco-updates/ \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  --name nominatim \
  mediagis/nominatim:4.1
```

`PBF_URL` in the above command points to Monaco's dataset.

If you would like to cover the entire planet you will need to download the planet dataset and you will need a min of 64GB RAM as per Nominatim hardware specs.